# Puppet: managehome on user type only works when user doesn't exist

Tags: puppet

I'm looking for clarification here. It seems the *managehome* attribute of the *user* defined type only works when the user doesn't exist. Have a look at this DSL

```
user { 'artifactory':
        ensure     => 'present',
        home       => '/home/artifactory',
        managehome => true,
}

file { '/home/artifactory/data':
        ensure  => link,
        target  => '/var/lib',
        require => User['artifactory'],
}
```

The first time I run this it works fine, however, if I delete the *artifactory* user's home directory, then run it again, puppet barfs.

**Error: Could not set 'link' on ensure: No such file or directory**

My first thought is **really**? Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#user-attribute-managehome)

> Whether to manage the home directory when managing the user. This will
>   create the home directory when ensure => present

If I delete the user and try again it works. So is this by design or is it a bug? It seems delicate to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a runtime perspective puppet checks the status of the user on the system and compares it against the manifest. If the user does not exist on the system then puppet runs the appropriate `useradd` command to create it. If the user is not supposed to exist, and does, then it runs the appropriate `userdel` command. If some attribute of the user, such as group membership, uid, name, etc, has changed then it issues the appropriate `gpasswd` or `usermod` command.

Unfortunately, the documentation on the user type isn't the clearest. The `managehome` parameter isn't so much making a statement about that directory as it is an option to the `useradd`, `usermod`, or `userdel` command. So if you set `managehome => true` and change the location of the home directory then it will be created, if you delete the user it will be deleted, and if you add the user it will be created. It does not, however, ensure that the directory exists at all times.

If this is required then I would recommend you create a file type and set an appropriate require. Something like this:

```
user { 'artifactory':
    ensure     => 'present',
    home       => '/home/artifactory',
    managehome => true,
}

file { 
  '/home/artifactory/data':
    ensure  => link,
    target  => '/var/lib',
    require => [ User['artifactory'], File['artifactoryhomedir'] ]; 
  '/home/artifactory':
    ensure => directory,
    alias => 'artifactoryhomedir',
    require => User['artifactory'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One question - how does puppet know to run the */home/artifactory* creation prior to */home/artifactory/data*? I'd expect to have to make that explicit with a `require => File['/home/artifactory']` on */home/artifactory/data*. I tried it though (as you have it) and it does work, so seems puppet is able to discern that relationship on its own?

Comment: @quickshiftin: Yeah, there should probably be another require on that. I simply forgot.

Comment: "Autorequires: If Puppet is managing the user or group that owns a file, the file resource will autorequire them. If Puppet is managing any parent directories of a file, the file resource will autorequire them." source: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.2.latest/type.html#file

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil: Cute! I need to read more up on the newer versions. I wrote most of my modules for 2.4 and have been fixing them so they continue to work but haven't done a good job of keeping up with changes like that.

Comment: As far as I know, the autorequire has been there for a long, long time.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7002). The planned solution is to keep the current behavior, but rename *managehome* to *createhome* to make it more clear.